# Trying to pass user input into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

So I'm working with XAMPP and I was following this tutorial on how to set up a website. Right now the webpage is takes a first name and last name. Once you submit it should place those into the database. I'm getting this error every time I try to test it: ***Connected "successfullyError: INSERT into 'user'('fname', 'lname') VALUES ('abc','xyz') You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''user'('fname', 'lname') VALUES ('abc','xyz')' at line 1***"

Here's what the html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="submit.php" method="post">
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the file that has the php code to connect the page to the database. I am new to php and I tried to locate the syntax error, but to no avail.

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['firstname'];
$y = $_POST['lastname'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db1";


//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{ 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "INSERT into 'user'('fname', 'lname') VALUES ('$x','$y')";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
  echo "That's going on your permanent record loser";  
}
else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Try to change `$sql = "INSERT into 'user'('fname', 'lname') VALUES ('$x','$y')";` to `$sql = "INSERT INTO user (fname, lname) VALUES ('$x','$y')";`

Comment: Didn't work. I tried something like that earlier.

Comment: what are the columns in `user`? If the column names are not being written correctly or you are missing columns it will not work. Also, check out `mysqli::bind_param()`. Right now this code is extremely insecure.

Comment: Your MySql query has qoute on the table name. Also use prepared statement.

Comment: @E2017 The columns are fname and lname. theres an id column as well but I set that to be Automatically iterated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem that I see that you use a single quote `'` to your table and column instead of using "`". The single quote are use as string delimiter.
Try changing this part

```
'user'('fname', 'lname')
```

into

```
`user`(`fname`, `lname`)
```

Comment: Oh wow I completely misread those in the tutorial. Thank you it works!